# Significato e uso dell'espressione "e te pareva"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, regional

In una conversazione sul [Bar Sport](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51244465#51244465) è apparsa l'espressione "e te pareva" nel contesto di uno scherzo. Non conosco questa espressione e non sono riuscita a trovarla su nessun dizionario. Una ricerca su Google, però, mi ha fatto vedere che si usa parecchio. Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa e come e quando si utilizza, facendo qualche esempio? Non dovrebbe essere "e ***ti*** pareva"?

Comment: _E te pareva_ dovrebbe essere la versione romanesca.

Comment: @abarisone:  Quindi dovrei aggiungere la tag "regional"? Tuttavia, l'ho trovata in testi che non mi sembrano per niente romaneschi.

Comment: Secondo me sì, anche se ormai è di uso comune in tutta Italia.

Comment: Va detto che il dialetto romanesco si sente spesso usare in film e televisione, specialmente dai comici, ed è ormai abbastanza "sdoganato" nell'uso comune: ci si può aspettare che l'italiano medio comprenda qualcuna delle sue espressioni più comuni --- specialmente quelle che, come "e te pareva", differiscono davvero poco dall'italiano standard. Stessa cosa, anche se forse in misura minore, per alcune espressioni del napoletano e, in misura decisamente minore, del milanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In romanesco (dialetto romano) "e te pareva" è una esclamazione di leggera delusione dovuta all'attesa che un fatto si svolga in positivo e invece termini con un finale scontato o negativo.

Esempio:

> Tizio: Ho preso tutto prima di incontrarci, non ho dimenticato niente. 
>       Caio:  Sì, ma hai portato il libro che t'avevo chiesto? 
>       Tizio: Ah no, quello no. 
>       Caio:  E te pareva. Mai una volta che me dai 'na soddisfazione.

Nell'esempio si può notare la disillusione di Caio (che parla in romanesco). 
Può esser visto come la contrazione di "*e te (ti) pareva che la cosa andasse come mi aspettavo, e invece no.*"

Comment: Vedrei bene Caio dire anche *mai 'na gioia* al posto di quell'ultima frase.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Magari Caio si esprime in modo personale ed evita di proposito frasi alla moda. :)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Cos'è questo di "mai 'na gioia"?

Comment: @Charo È una frase che è diventata popolare di recente, soprattutto nel romano; non so se si possa definire "meme", ma è qualcosa di simile. Vuol dire più o meno "ahimé, mai una volta che mi capiti qualcosa di felice" (per sfortuna o incapacità/volere altrui).

Comment: Da romana, uso l’espressione «E te pareva» (alternandola con «Figuriamoci!») per commentare un fatto che avevo già previsto con esito negativo.